# Get data-ref using selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website with such class:

```html
<html>
    <body><div class="class1" data-ref="data"></div></body>
<html>
```

I want to use selenium in python 3 to get the `data-ref` (i.e. "data").

I know you can get the text using `.text` is there something like that for `data-ref`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To retrieve the value of `data-ref` attribute i.e. **data** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']").get_attribute("data-ref"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("div.class1").get_attribute("data-ref"))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
get_attribute("attribute name")
```

In your case

```
get_attribute("data-ref")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the element using its xpath and then can find the `data-ref` value using `get_attribute` method.

You can do it like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']")
# Find the value of data-ref
value = element.get_attribute("data-ref")
```